# css clip-path not working on safari browser including 9

Tags: css, polygon, point-in-polygon, clip-path

My code is [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZdzVo). I am creating shapes which are working fine when i am working with chrome. but on safari things are not working fine.

```
.left-triangle{
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background: #E84343;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 1%, 0% 100%, 99% 37%);
    clip-path: polygon(0% 1%, 0% 100%, 99% 37%);   
}
```

can anyone help me for this?